Camera not working on Raspberry pi 5
I use the newest Ubuntu 24.10 and trying to make my Pi cameras to work, imx477 (original HQ camera) on CSI/DSI port 0 and imx219 on port 1. None of them work with the pre-installed camera app neither cheese. Also I installed libcamera, but when I run "libcamera-hello" or any other libcamera app terminal shows "command not found", even if libcamera is already installed.
Can anyone help me with that, because i had the same thing with my raspberry pi 4b and Ubuntu 23.04
Thanks.

Please be clear & precise with details; the latest Ubuntu release is 24.10? (2024-October release) so do you mean that; or Ubuntu Core 24 (the latest release of that IoT/Cloud product).

Ubuntu 24.10, not Core release, with the raspberry pi 4b it's Ubuntu 23.04 also desktop.

Please amend your question & be specific/clear with details.  Also correct Ubuntu 23 as there was no snap only release of Ubuntu in 2023.
